# My webpage google map displaying blank after adding https to site

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

My webpage google map displaying blank after adding https to site
NO error showing in console.
i changed the everything related to https. included https url in api key credential section of google cloud console.
changed api url to https

still no map dispalying.

```
jQuery(function($) {
// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&key=MY_API_KEY";
document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function attachClickHandler(marker){
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  var elem = $(marker.url);
  console.log(marker.title);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: elem.offset().top - 200
  }, 1000 );        
});
}

function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var markers = new Array();
<?php $i= 1; foreach($locations as $l):  ?>
  var marker = ['<?php echo $i; ?>', <?php echo $l->latitude; ?>, <?php echo $l->longitude; ?>, '#<?php echo $i; ?>'];
  markers.push(marker);
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  

for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0],
      url: markers[i][3],
      label: {color: '#fff', fontSize: '16px', fontWeight: '600', text: markers[i][0]}
  });
  bounds.extend(position);

  attachClickHandler(marker);   


}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(8);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To rule out API key restriction-related issues, try unrestricting your API key within Google's Cloud Console. If your map loads successfully when using an unrestricted API key then that means you need to add the correct [HTTP referrers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) for your domain. E.g.:

https://*.example.com/* 

https://example.com/*

And make sure that you allow the JavaScript API if you have set [API restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_restriction).

If the map still doesn't load with an unrestricted key, then something else is wrong, e.g. there's an issue with your billing account, you added the wrong API key to your site, the JavaScript API is disabled on your project...

You may need to contact Google's [Technical Support Team](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support) if the issue persists after double checking all this.

Hope this helps!